# Setting the default value in a function?

Tags: r, function, default-value

I have a simple density function below:

```
dpower <- function(x, b, r){
if ((b <= 0 | r <= 0)) 
return("Wrong parameters entered!")
else{
 density.temp <- (r/b)*(x/b)^(r - 1)
 density.temp[which(x >= b | x <= 0)] <- NA
 return(density.temp)
 } 
}
```

This function returns density corresponding to value x from the specified distribution with parameters b and r. I'd like to set the default value on x that if the user doesn't specify x, the default values passes through. We can simply set dpower <- function(x = x.default, b, r)... however, my default value depends on r and b. How can I do that? suppose the default value for x is:

```
seq(from = 0.05, to = b, by = 0.001)
```

Thanks for your help,

Comment: How do you intend to call the function, in the case where 'x' is missing?

Comment: Hi Matthew, with only b and r. I want R to know that if x is not called (i.e. dpower has only two arguments), then R uses the default value of x.

Comment: It can be done, but it's a lot easier if the 'x' argument is last in the list.

Comment: Yeah, I see...well then we can put it last.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

```
dpower <- function(b, r, x = seq(from = 0.05, to = b, by = 0.001))
....
```

Comment: Good. Is there anyway to check in the function whether the x argument has been specified when the the function is called? something that returns TRUE or FALSE?

Comment: Yes, `missing(x)`. This will test whether an argument (`x`) within a function as been specified within the call.

Answer (score 11):

You can set the value of X to `NULL` and have one of the first lines of your function be

```
 if(is.null(x))
     x <- seq(from = 0.05, to = b, by = 0.001)
```